# Let $Te_n=e_{n+1}$ show that $T:H\to H$ is isometric.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ and let $T:H\to H$ be the (only) bounded operator that satisfies:

$T(e_n)=e_{n+1}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
Show that $T$ is isometric but not unitary.

Let $H_1,H_2$ be Hilbert spaces and  $T : H_1→ H_2$. Then
T is called unitary if:

$T$ is surjective, and
$T$ preserves the inner product.

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces.
$T:X\to Y$.
Then $T$ is called isometric if it preserves the norm:
$||Tx||=||x||\quad \forall x\in X$.

I tried showing that T is isometric:

Since $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of H:

Let $x\in H$. We want to show that $||Tx||=||x||$.
From a theorem in functional analysis, we have
$||x||^2=\sum_{n} |<x,e_n>|^2$ for every $x\in H$.So we can substitute $Tx\in H$ but i cannot see how to use then the given definition of the operator $T$?
From the same theorem, we get also:
$x=\sum_{n} <x,e_n>e_n$ for all $x\in H$ but then how to use this for showing that the operator is not unitary i.e. it does not preserve inner product, using the definition of $T$.

Comment: You probably want to identify $H$ with the sequence space $\ell^2$. Then $T$ takes the sequence $(x_1, x_2, \ldots )$ to $(0,x_1, x_2 , \ldots)$, and you can check directly that the norm (hence the inner product) is preserved by $T$. As for why $T$ is not unitary, well it's not surjective since it doesn't reach $e_1$, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned all the data you need.

You have,using that $T$ is bounded for the first equality, and the continuity of the inner product in the fourth equality,
\begin{align}
\|Tx\|^2&=\Big\|\sum_n\langle x,e_n\rangle\,Te_n\Big\|^2
=\Big\|\sum_n\langle x,e_n\rangle\,e_{n+1}\Big\|^2\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_n|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2=\|x\|^2.
\end{align}
So $T$ is an isometry. But it is not surjective, since $e_1$ is orthogonal to the range of $T$.

Comment: It was just detail on how to calculate the norm. I have removed it. The range of T is the closure of the span of $e_2,e_3,\ldots$.