# Describing $T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal series in $H$ and $(\lambda_n)$ be a scalar bounded series.
Let $T$ be the (only) operator in $B(H)$ such that:
$Te_n=\lambda_n e_n$ for all $n\in N$, and $Tx=0$ for all $x$ orthogonal to $(e_n)$.

Describe $T^*$.

It seems related to [Let $Te_n=e_{n+1}$ show that $T:H\to H$ is isometric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104691/let-te-n-e-n1-show-that-th-to-h-is-isometric)

But not much similar.

Comment: We have $$ T = \sum_{n} \lambda_n \vert e_n \rangle \langle e_n \vert $$ and thus $$ T^* =   \sum_{n} \overline{\lambda_n} \vert e_n \rangle \langle e_n \vert.$$ where by the bar I mean complex conjugation.

Comment: Hi i didn't understand the sign | > , it shoud be the diagonal operator which is defined by $Tx=\sum_n \lambda_n <x,e_n>e_n$ ? Right

Comment: Ah sorry, that is the physics notation for what you wrote :) they are called, bra and ket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me prove that $T^*$ vanishes on the complement of the span of the $e_n$'s (call this orthogonal complement $X$, i.e. $X:=(\text{span}\{ e_n \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N} \})^\perp$). Fix some $x\in X$, then we have for all $y\in X$
$$ \langle T^*(x), y\rangle = \langle x, T(y) \rangle = \langle x, 0 \rangle = 0. $$
Thus, $T^*(x)$ is in the orthogonal complement of $X$. Now we also test on the $e_n$'s and find
$$ \langle T^*(x), e_n \rangle = \langle x, T(e_n) \rangle = \lambda_n \langle x, e_n \rangle = 0 $$
as $X$ is the orthogonal complement of the span of the $e_n$'s. Hence, $T^*(x)$ orthogonal to all elements in $H$ and thus equal to zero.

Now you can try to play a similar game to determine the values of $T^*(e_n)$. You will get $T^*(e_n)= \overline{\lambda}_n e_n$ (bar means complex conjugation).

**Added:** Let me also do the second case. We have
$$ \langle T^*(e_n) - \overline{\lambda}_n e_n, e_m \rangle
= \langle e_n, T(e_m) \rangle - \lambda_n \langle e_n, e_m \rangle
= \lambda_m \langle e_n, e_m \rangle - \lambda_n \langle e_n, e_m \rangle
= \lambda_m \delta_{n,m} - \lambda_n \delta_{n,m} =0. $$
On the other hand, we have for $x$ in the orthogonal complement of $X$
$$  \langle T^*(e_n) - \overline{\lambda}_n e_n, x \rangle
= \langle e_n, T(x) \rangle - \lambda_n \langle e_n, x \rangle
= \langle e_n, 0 \rangle - \lambda_n 0 =0. $$
So again, $T^*(e_n) - \overline{\lambda}_n e_n$ is orthogonal to all elements in $H$ and hence we have $T^*(e_n) - \overline{\lambda}_n e_n=0$, which implies $T^*(e_n) = \overline{\lambda}_n e_n$.

Comment: Hello @Severin Schraven thanks, i did not much understand hoe $X$ is defined, and how the $T^*$ is described in the end..

Comment: I defined $X$ to be the orthogonal complement of $span \{  e_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Also I wrote how it is described just in the end of my answer.

Comment: @Maths1999_ is it clear now?

Comment: Hi, i think so but where you write $<x,e_n>$ isn't should be $\overline{\lambda}$? @Severin Schraven

Comment: I am working with the assumption that the scalar product is linear in the second slot and anti-linear in the first slot. In case you have the opposite definition, you have to put some more bars :)

Comment: Hi @Severin Schraven can you explain the rest of the proof please?

Comment: You want to show that $T^*(e_n)=\overline{\lambda}_n e_n$. So you want to show that $T^*(e_n)-\overline{\lambda}_n e_n$ is orthogonal to all elements in $H$. Test first against $x\in X$ and then against $e_m$ and see that the scalar product vanishes in both cases (for the $e_m$ you need to distinguish $m=n$ and $m\neq n$). Ok?

Comment: Hello @Severin Schraven i tried what you said,  but I did not get that the inner product is 0! And, when you say "orthogonal to all elements in $H$. Why is actually true? Thanks

Comment: @Maths1999_ It is orthogonal to all elements in $H$, because it is orthogonal to all $e_n$ and all element in the orthogonal complement of the span of all the $e_n$. Try to write this down rigorously (it is not hard, but also not trivial).